# Мыльный и размытый интерфейс vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Писал я значит код, отвернулся, смотрю на мой код, а он мыльный. Я думал у меня что-то со зрением, но нет.
Интерфейс у vs code стал мыльный. Причем началось это само по себе. Ничего вроде не менял.
Я подумал, что баг, перезапустил, и всё работало как надо. Но в последнее время перезапуск не помогает
Что с этим делать?
Обновление установлено последнее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

windows 10 1909
nvidia gtx 1660
у меня два монитора, возможно из-за этого, но два монитора у меня уже давно, а проблема появилась недавно

Comment: Уберите, пожалуйста, метку ide. Даже в описании метки vscode написано, что это *текстовой редактор*

Comment: совсем непонятно окружение - операционная система, видеокарта. Может это вообще через цитрикс (удаленный рабочий стол) и тогда все ок, там так бывает.

Comment: @Shift там написано *текстовый редактор* для людей, которые не знают что такое IDE. VSCode — это IDE, влючающая в себя текстовый редактор, терминал, менеджер файлов, репозитория, плагинов, парсер структуры и много чего ещё, особенно добавляемого через плагины, вроде специфических для отдельных языков линтеров или дебаггеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/9szgkp/visual_studio_code_blurry/

- NVIDIA Control Panel
- Manage 3D settings
- Program Settings
- Select VS Code from dropdown or add it if it's not there
- Set "Antialiasing - FXAA" to OFF

Answer (score 0):

Панель управления Nvidia,
Управления параметрами 3D,
Программные настройки,
Добавить code.exe, который находится в папке Microsoft VS code,
Выключить "Увеличение резкости изображения",
Выключить "Сглаживание FXAA"

Comment: Это просто перевод соседнего ответа

Comment: Нет, мне ответ выше не помог, а то что написал я помогло

Comment: Отличие от другого ответа только в "Выключить "Увеличение резкости изображения", остальное совпадает.

Answer (score 0):

Стрелка возле открытия нового терминала > Configure Terminal Settings > Gpu Acceleration > off